# Responsive JavaScript with text replacing

Tags: javascript, html, css, replace, responsive

I want to replace a text depending on the screen size (`max-width:700px`). I want to use JavaScript to replace and `if/else` for the screen size.

Here is my code:

```css
.membre5 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 50vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  /* transform: translateX(50%); */
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}

.card {
  margin-left: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 540px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

img.skin {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: auto;
}

.title {
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nom {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  color: inherit;
  color: white;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:hover,
a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.card {
  font-family: odin rounded;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="membre5">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="skin" src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/7/19/82b5f414cf833e05e6dd86cef344a52f-full.png" alt="ALLiAnce" style="width:100%">
    <h1 class="nom">ALLiAnce</h1>
    <p class="title" id="comp">Admin et remplaçant</p>
    <script>
      function myFunction(x) {
        if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
          function test() {
            var str = document.getElementById("comp").innerHTML;
            var res = str.replace("Admin et remplaçant", "Membre");
            document.getElementById("comp").innerHTML = res;
          }
        }
      }

      var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
      myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
      x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
    </script>
    <p><button>Contact</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the text that I want to be changed: `"Admin et remplaçant"` to `"Membre"`, but the script doesn't work, I don't know why (I take the script from many websites and put all-in-one). Can you say what is wrong, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any error or just not the expected output?

Comment: I don't have any error.

Comment: I think you are not running `test()`. It `if (x.matches) {`  evaluates to `true` you define a function `test()` in which the replacement takes place only that is not being run.

Comment: it's because of the closure. You're never calling `test()` it's a nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. On load, call the function to check the `max-width` and add a listener to `resize` event. The following makes the text to change if the width exceeds or lesser than the `max-width`.

Using listeners of `MediaQueryList`, [MediaQueryList.addListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener)

```js
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 200px)");
function matches()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("comp");
    elem.innerHTML = mql.matches ? "Membre" : "Admin et remplaçant";
}
mql.addListener(matches);
```

```html
<p class="title" id="comp">Admin et remplaçant</p>
```

[MediaQueryList.onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange)

```js
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 200px)");
function matches()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("comp");
    elem.innerHTML = mql.matches ? "Membre" : "Admin et remplaçant";
}
mql.onchange = matches;
```

```html
<p class="title" id="comp">Admin et remplaçant</p>
```

Using `window.onresize`,

```js
function matches()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("comp");
    elem.innerHTML = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 200px)").matches ? "Membre" : "Admin et remplaçant";
}
window.onresize = function(event) {
    matches();
};
matches();
```

```html
<p class="title" id="comp">Admin et remplaçant</p>
```

Comment: You don't need `onresize`, since you're using anyway a `MediaQueryList`, you can use `addListener` or `onchange` if the media query is triggered: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange

Comment: @ZER0 Thanks. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just not calling your test function after you declare it to me

```
function myFunction(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        function test() {
            var str = document.getElementById("comp").innerHTML; 
            var res = str.replace("Admin et remplaçant", "Membre");
            document.getElementById("comp").innerHTML = res;
        }
        //CALL TEST FUNCTION
        test();
    } 
}
```